# Dse spark to extract data from cluster and load to another cluster

Tags: apache-spark, datastax, datastax-enterprise

We have two DSE clusters and we want to use DSE spark to extract the data from cluster1 and do some transformations and load into cluster2.

How to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You can load from Cluster1 to Cluster2 with DSE spark. 
The only prerequisite is to make the keyspace and table already in Cluster 2 , where the data would be loaded.

For the following setup:

**Source Cluster**

Cluster 1 :

Keyspace : rrtest

table : rrexample

**Destination Cluster**

Cluster 2:

keyspace : test

table : example

Now the first step here is to create the keyspaces and tables. 
Say the table has the following Description ( created from cql shell)

On cluster 1  :

```
CREATE TABLE rrtest.rrexample 
(
    username text PRIMARY KEY,
    password text,
    state text
)
```

On cluster 2 :

```
CREATE TABLE test.example 
(
    username text PRIMARY KEY,
    password text,
    state text
)
```

Scala Code for migration to cluster2

```
************ Load from Cluster 1*************

import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql._
import java.net.InetAddress
val myrdd = { implicit val src = CassandraConnector(Set(InetAddress.getByName("<ip : host1>"))); sc.cassandraTable("rrtest", "rrexample").select("username", "password", "state") }

************ Migrate to Cluster 2************

{     implicit val dst = CassandraConnector(Set(InetAddress.getByName("<ip:host2>")));    myrdd.saveToCassandra("test", "example") }
```